# iOs: Why are IBOutlets not wired up after [[alloc] init], but are after viewDidUnload: has been called

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I have a simple `UINavigationViewController` which when a certain item is selected creates a modal view that has an `UIImageView` (PostcardViewController below) inside it. However, if I call

```
PostcardViewController *postcardViewController = [[PostcardViewController alloc] init];
postcardViewController.imageView.image = image; 
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:postcardViewController animated:YES];
```

`postcardViewController.imageView` is nill, and the image never gets shown. If I switch the latter two lines, and make it:

```
PostcardViewController *postcardViewController = [[PostcardViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:postcardViewController animated:YES];
postcardViewController.imageView.image = image;
```

`postcardViewController.imageView` is set, and it shows up fine. Everything is wired up in Interface Builder and PostcardViewController doesn't have any specific code in it. By debugging, I came to find out, that it was after [`viewDidLoad`] was called that imageView was wired up, and [`viewDidLoad`] got called when I called [`presentModalViewController`].

Why is this, and also, am I doing something wrong here? I figured I should have the entire view set up before I actually showed it, but as of right now, I have to display it before I can completely set it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've only created the view controller using alloc+init, not the view itself. The view is lazily loaded, i.e. the first time it is used. To force the view to be created before it is actually shown, do this:

```
PostcardViewController *postcardViewController = [[PostcardViewController alloc] init];
postcardViewController.view; // Forces the view to be loaded
postcardViewController.imageView.image = image; // Will no longer be nil
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:postcardViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

The outlets are nil because initializing a controller doesn't load the nib/xib. Only after the view property is accessed (like when presented) is the nib loaded and wired to controller.

Let the `PostcardViewController` have the responsibility of setting the imageView's image in viewDidLoad. Create an image property to pass the UIImage.

```
PostcardViewController *pvc= [[PostcardViewController alloc] init];
pvc.image = image; 
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:pvc animated:YES];
[pvc release];
```

In PostcardViewController.h

```
  ...
  UIImage *image
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

In PostcardViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because UIViewControllers load their views lazily. So the view isn't loaded until you actually attempt to present it.